# Uploading file to Google Storage with signed Url

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-storage, pre-signed-url, cloudflare-workers, shopify-hydrogen

I'm trying to upload a file directly from the frontend to Google Storage. I'm working on hydrogen environment (similar to cloudflare) so I can't use normal google libraries in the backend.

Whenever I try to upload one file I get the following problem:

```
<?xml version='1.0' encoding='UTF-8'?><Error><Code>SignatureDoesNotMatch</Code><Message>The request signature we calculated does not match the signature you provided. Check your Google secret key and signing method.</Message><StringToSign>PUT

image/png
1684774590
/BUCKET_NAME/92f3f1ab-1272-4ad8-acb7-b89c06523641</StringToSign></Error>
```

My frontend code:

```
export const uploadFile = async (file: File, signedUrl: string) => {
  const response = await axios.put(signedUrl, file, {
     headers: {
       'Content-Type': file.type,
    },
  });

  return response;
};
```

My backend code:

```
export const getSignedUrl = async (
  bucketName: string,
  privateKey: string,
  accountEmail: string,
) => {
  const expiration = Math.floor(Date.now() / 1000) + 60 * 60; // 1 hour from now
  const objectName = uuidv4();

  // Construct the canonical resource.
  const canonicalResource = `/${bucketName}/${objectName}`;

  // Construct the string to sign.
  const stringToSign =
    `PUT\n` + // HTTP verb
    `\n` + // Content-MD5 (empty)
    `image/png\n` + // Content-Type
    `${expiration}\n` + // Expires
    `${canonicalResource}`; // CanonicalizedResource

  const secret = base64Decode(privateKey);
  const textEncoder = new TextEncoder();
  const secretUint8Array = textEncoder.encode(secret);

  const key = await crypto.subtle.importKey(
    'raw',
    secretUint8Array,
    {name: 'HMAC', hash: 'SHA-256'},
    false,
    ['sign'],
  );

  const stringToSignUint8Array = textEncoder.encode(stringToSign);

  const signatureUint8Array = await crypto.subtle.sign(
    'HMAC',
    key,
    stringToSignUint8Array,
  );
  const signature = base64Encode(signatureUint8Array);

  // Finally, you can construct the signed URL.
  const signedUrl =
    `https://storage.googleapis.com/${bucketName}/${objectName}` +
    `?GoogleAccessId=${accountEmail}` +
    `&Expires=${expiration}` +
    `&Signature=${encodeURIComponent(signature)}`;

  return signedUrl;
};
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: I do not see a problem with your code. 1) You are using V2 signing. If you are going thru this much trouble to not use the libraries, use the current signing method V4. 2) The client request (method, Content-type, and URI) must match the signing process. Show the complete HTTP request. 3) If the HTTP request is exactly the same, add debug code to print the value of `stringToSign`. Then compare that with the error message.

Comment: Thanks. The library is currently a limitation from Oxygen. For now I'm just using firebase functions to supply where I'm limited by the environment. I'll check the v4 method more careful later once I need to optimize the process :)

Answer (score 1):

When the calculated signature in the request does not match the signature given, the "SignatureDoesNotMatch" error is returned.

1. Check the consistency of `bucketName` and `objectName` as well as the `stringToSign` created on the frontend and backend.
2. Check that the `base64Encode` and `base64Decode` functions for the private key are functioning properly.
3. Verify whether it's essential to use `encodeURIComponent` for the signature in the signed URL.
4. Verify that the hashing and signing algorithms used by the frontend and the backend are identical.
5. Make that the backend uses `crypto.subtle.importKey` to import the private key properly.
6. To find any inconsistencies, compare the signature generated on the frontend with the one computed on the backend.

You may check this Google documentation about [Signed URLs](https://cloud.google.com/storage/docs/access-control/signed-urls).